# How to update Controls from static method?

Tags: c#, .net, controls, static, wpf-controls

Hello
Why I haven't access to my private control on form (e.g. ListBox) from a static method? 
How to update control in this case?

EDIT 1.

my code:

```
ThreadStart thrSt = new ThreadStart(GetConnected);
        Thread thr = new Thread(thrSt);
        thr.Start();
```

and

```
static void GetConnected()
    {
        //update my ListBox
    }
```

So it must be void, without param and be static, right?

EDIT 2.

If someone need **solution** in WPF then should try this:

```
private void GetConnected()
    {
        myListBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                    new Action(() =>
                    {
                        myListBox.Items.Add("something");
                    }
                               )
                 );
    }
```

Comment: insert your code to understand why you want to make update in static method

Comment: Why you defined it static? did you access this method from any other class?

Comment: it can have parameter and you can pass its parameter as object array

Comment: Yes, you're right. It needn't be static

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Static methods cannot access instance state (such as a non-static control). Either remove `static` from the method declaration, or pass a reference to the control as argument to the method:

```
private static void SomeMethod(ListBox listBox)
{
    listBox.Items.Add("Some element");
}
```

...and call it like so:

```
SomeMethod(MyListBox);
```

**Update**
There are different ways to do asynchronous things in the UI (now assuming winforms). I would recommend you to look into using `BackgroundWorker` (search here on SO; plenty of examples). If you really want to do it by creating threads on your own, here is one way to do that:

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
    string newElement = FetchNextElementToAdd():
    SafeUpdate(() => yourListBox.Items.Add(newElement));
}

private void SafeUpdate(Action action)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(action);
    }
    else
    {
        action();
    }
}
```

...and to call it:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(SomeMethod);
thread.Start();
```

You can also use the thread pool (preferred over creating your own threads, given that you don't expect them to run for very long):

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => SomeMethod());
```

Comment: I must call this method in another Thread so AFAIK it must be static and must be without param and must return void, right?

Comment: @Saint_pl: I assume that you mean that you want to launch call the method on a separate thread (as in `new Thread(YourMethod)`). If that is the case then no, it does not need to be static. Parameterless and returning void yes, but not necessarily static.

Comment: Hmm, that's right :) I don't know why earlier it didn't work :)

Comment: I'm wrong or sth but in wpf there's no sth like InvokeRequired? So it's problem because I have error: "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."

Comment: O, there's sth better :) Sth called Dispatcher :)

Comment: @Saint_pl: yes, I missed the wpf-controls tag. My bad. You should use Dispatcher.

Answer (score 22):

i found another answer on the web

write this in the form class:

```
static Form1 frm;
```

and in the form constructor:

```
frm = this;
```

now we can use the variable "frm" for accessing all of controls on the form.

somewhere in a static method:

```
frm.myListBox.Items.Add("something");
```

Comment: Wow! You just saved my day. Thank you so much!

Comment: Worked for me! So simple. Wonder what the downside of this is ...???

Answer (score 3):

I just found a new and different way to update a control from a static method. but we have to choose unique names for our controls

```
foreach (Form tmp in Application.OpenForms)
    foreach (System.Windows.Forms.Control temp in tmp.Controls)
        if (temp.Name == "textBox1")
            temp.Text = "it works :)";
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass a reference to the control to your static method, or something that contains them. static methods cant access non static fields/methods/etc. dont declare your control as static, i'm not even sure if its possible, but if it was, it would cause you problems you dont even want to know about.

Answer (score 1):

easiest solution for adding an item to a listbox from a static method:

1. Add on your Form1 `public static ListBox frm;`
2. After InitializeComponent() add `frm = this.listBox1;`
3. from your static method call `Form1.frm.Items.Add(myitem)`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access "this", "ui" or any function in MainWindow from a static function.

To solve this problem, make a public pointer of Mainwindow

```
Mainwindow *THIS;
```

before calling the callback function (the static function), assign this to the pointer THIS

```
THIS=this;
```

Now, you can use THIS instead of this.

for example:

```
THIS->listBox->Items->Add("Some element");
```